how to add linear correlation using pandas
this is my code and my result, here i want to add regression line or i want to see the linear correlation and i tried with so many way but i couldn't do it.
can you help me please?
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('/home/beki/Desktop/Final_report9.csv')
df

ax1 = df.plot(kind='scatter', y='log_LUM_Ha', x='log_AGN_LUM(type-2)', color='b', marker = '^', alpha = 0.5 )
ax2 = df.plot(kind='scatter', y='log_Lum_OII', x='log_AGN_LUM(type-2)', color='r', ax=ax1, marker = 's')
ax3 = df.plot(kind='scatter', y='log_LUM_H_beta', x='log_AGN_LUM(type-2)', color='c', ax=ax1, marker = 'x')
ax4 = df.plot(kind='scatter', y='log_LUM_OIII', x='log_AGN_LUM(type-2)', color='g', ax=ax1, marker = 'o')

plt.xlabel('AGN_LUM')
plt.ylabel('Luminosity of emission lines')
plt.legend
plt.title('AGN Luminosity Vs Luminosity of emission lines', weight='bold', size=12)
plt.legend(["log_LUM_Ha", "log_Lum_OII", "log_LUM_H_beta", "log_LUM_OIII"], loc="lower right")

enter image description here

Have you looked into seaborn's lmplot? It can accomplish your scatter plot for each variable and apply a linear regression line between points.
https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lmplot.html

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I am able to achieve this using the matplotlib and scipy modules.
I use numpy to generate random numbers, but you can just use your pandas data (from the "inal_report9.csv" file in the question) . I do note that this could be done purely in pandas, but i personally find it a bit limited for graphs compared to matplotlib.
here is my code:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

# Generate random data for the scatter plot
x = np.random.rand(100)
y = 2 * x + np.random.normal(0, 0.1, 100)

# Perform linear regression
slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(x, y)

# Create the scatter plot
plt.scatter(x, y)

# Add the regression line
plt.plot(x, slope * x + intercept, color='red')

# Add labels and title
plt.xlabel('X-axis')
plt.ylabel('Y-axis')
plt.title('Scatter Plot with Regression Line')

# Show the plot
plt.show()

And this is the output:

You can change the x-axis, and y-axis names and the title yourself and insert your own (pandas) data.
